# What's the best way to see files of an updated git bare repository? (concept of ls-tree)

Tags: git, bare, git-ls-tree

I'm looking for a way to see the files on a git bare repository that were updated by other remote but without do a pull in my repository.

I'll try to describe my doubt using an **example locally**.

I create a folder, add two files and make a new repository.

```
> mkdir stackOF && cd stackOF
> touch file1 file2
> git init
```

Then I create a bare repository from this repo.

```
> cd .. && git clone --bare stackOF stackOF.git
```

Now I want to create two clones of that bare repo and simulate some actions of too coworkers.

```
> git clone stackOF.git stackOF.clone1
> git clone stackOF.git stackOF.clone2
```

First, `clone1` will create a file, commit and push the change.

```
> cd stackOF.clone1 && touch file_clone1
> git add . && git commit -m "File from clone 1."
> git push
```

Second, `clone2` will create a file and only commit.

```
> cd ../stackOF.clone2 && touch file_clone2
> git add . && git commit -m "File from clone 2."
```

At this point starts my doubt over the `ls-tree` concept. Executing the next command I'd expect to see the file pushed by the clone1 but I receive the following:

```
> git ls-tree origin
100644 blob e69de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5392    file1
100644 blob e69de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5392    file2
```

I want to receive a result like doing the ls-tree command at the bare repository directory:

```
> cd ../stackOF.git
> git ls-tree master
100644 blob e69de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5392    file1
100644 blob e69de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5392    file2
100644 blob e69de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5392    file_clone1
```

Studying this case, I found a command that shows me what I want but with a lot of other informations. So, returning to the `clone2` and executing the command:

```
> cd ../stackOF.clone2
> git archive -v --remote=file:///f/gits/stackOF.git master
pax_global_header00006660000000000000000000000064133246307500014515gustar00rootroot0000000000000052 comment=0085439d6a07481e6a21db545edd3f7960c038e2
file1000066400000000000000000000000001332463075000117720ustar00rootroot00000000000000file2000066400000000000000000000000001332463075000117730ustar00rootroot00000000000000file_clone1000066400000000000000000000000001332463075000131520ustar00rootroot00000000000000remote: file1
remote: file2
remote: file_clone1
```

Summarizing, I'm on the `clone2` repository and looking which files is on the bare repository without make a pull. But I want something much clean like using `ls_tree` on the bare repository.

Comment: Git is decentralized system. You need to `fetch` remote repository to know what is going here.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @PetSerAl. I'm only studying if it's possible to make a request command to do that, like I did with `git archive` without a previous `fetch` command.

Comment: Someone has a more interesting answer?
Summarizing, I want to 'consult' the bare repository to know what files are there without make a pull. In my example I did that with the archive command but I guess were a poor solution and with a dirty response.